# Is the MATLAB function of 'reshape' available in any Java library?

Tags: java, matlab, reshape

I am trying to use the functionality of the reshape function available in MATLAB in Java. Are there any implementations of reshape available in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this (modified a little) on the [sun forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5429447).

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] ori = new double[][] { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12} };
        double[][] res = reshape(ori,2,6);

        for(int i = 0;i<ori.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<ori[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(ori[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i = 0;i<res.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<res[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(res[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }



    }

    public static double[][] reshape(double[][] A, int m, int n) {
        int origM = A.length;
        int origN = A[0].length;
        if(origM*origN != m*n){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("New matrix must be of same area as matix A");
        }
        double[][] B = new double[m][n];
        double[] A1D = new double[A.length * A[0].length];

        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<A.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<A[0].length;j++){
                A1D[index++] = A[i][j];
            }
        }

        index = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<m;j++){
                B[j][i] = A1D[index++];
            }

        }
        return B;
    }
}
```

test output is

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 
4.0 5.0 6.0 
7.0 8.0 9.0 
10.0 11.0 12.0 

1.0 3.0 5.0 7.0 9.0 11.0 
2.0 4.0 6.0 8.0 10.0 12.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Glowcoder ! Can you suggest me some idea for reshaping form one dimension to another dimension. I am looking to convert a 1-dimensional(a[50400]) array into 7- dimensional array (b[2][12][4][5][5][7][3]). Another case is to convert a 2d array (c[1260][12]) into a 3d array (d[60][21][12])

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but for any future visitors.
There is the [Eclipse January](https://github.com/eclipse/january), which supports such operation

> This is a library for handling Data in Java. It is inspired in part by NumPy and aims to provide similar functionality.

It does have support for `reshape` function on `Dataset`.
You can go over the [BasicExample](https://github.com/eclipse/january/blob/master/org.eclipse.january.examples/src/org/eclipse/january/examples/dataset/BasicExample.java)

(code from the above example)

```
Dataset another = DatasetFactory
                    .createFromObject(new double[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34 })
                    .reshape(3, 3);
```